# Get next date in lucene index

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net

I am storing a listing of events in a lucene.net index, which has a start date field.  I would like to add a button for the user to click to see the next event (based on the start date field) relative to the event they are viewing.

I'm currently using a `ConstantScoreRangeQuery` search to do a search of events between two dates, but not sure how I can get the next date in the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres a simple way to do it using a `TermEnum`

```cs
        RAMDirectory ramDir = new RAMDirectory();

        IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(ramDir, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT));

        Document d = new Document();
        Field date = new Field("date", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
        d.Add(date);

        DateTime first = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(5));
        DateTime second = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(4));
        DateTime third = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(3));
        DateTime fourth = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2));
        DateTime fifth = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

        date.SetValue(DateTools.DateToString(first, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE));
        iw.AddDocument(d);
        date.SetValue(DateTools.DateToString(second, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE));
        iw.AddDocument(d);
        date.SetValue(DateTools.DateToString(third, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE));
        iw.AddDocument(d);
        date.SetValue(DateTools.DateToString(fourth, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE));
        iw.AddDocument(d);
        date.SetValue(DateTools.DateToString(fifth, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE));
        iw.AddDocument(d);

        iw.Commit();

        IndexReader ir = iw.GetReader();

        var termEnum = ir.Terms(new Term("date", DateTools.DateToString(second, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE)));

        if (termEnum.Next())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTools.StringToDate(termEnum.Term().Text()));
            Console.WriteLine(DateTools.StringToDate(termEnum.Term().Text()).Day == third.Day);
        }

        Console.Read();
```